# In Varnish stats, what does "Backend conn. reuses" and "recycles" mean?

Tags: varnish

I have varnish installed and I think it's working properly (not sure if it matters but I am using `iptables` reroute method to route ports `incoming:80 > varnish:8080 > apache:80`

Anyway, In `varnishstat` I see a pretty high Hitrate average (60-80%) which I am working on but I am unclear at what all of the stats presented by `varnishstat`

Specifically the following Backend stats:

```
380         0.00         0.26 Backend conn. success
10122      15.00         6.85 Backend conn. reuses
267         0.00         0.18 Backend conn. was closed
10391      15.00         7.04 Backend conn. recycles
```

I've read a blog post called "[Varnishstat for dummies](http://kristianlyng.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/varnishstat-for-dummies/)" which outlines a lot of details of varnishstat (I recommend it for beginners) but it does not go over these Backend stats.

Feel free to explain here or link to a resource I've missed :)

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first number ("Backend connections initiated") is the total number of (TCP socket) connections that has been opened from Varnish to the backend. This number is a counter.
>
> "Backend connections recycled" is increased whenever we have a keep-alive connection that is put back into the pool of connections. It has not yet been used, but it might be, unless the backend closes it.
>
> "Backend connections reused" is increased whenever we actually reuse a connection from the pool of backend connections.
>
> Last, "Backend connections unused", are the number of available connections at any given time. This number is an absolute number, and will increase and decrease during operation.

Source : https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/StatsExplained

Answer (score 1):

ok, so from thinking about it, i have the following theory on what each of these mean:

1. **Backend conn. Success:** number of connections that required a backend connection (to apache in your case) and got a response
2. **Backend conn. Reuses:** number of connections which needed a backend connection, and used one that was already open, reducing the creation and tear down of the connection...
3. **Backend conn. was closed:** not 100% sure on this, but I think it might be connection that were either closed before data came back (error) or a connection that Varnish though was open, but was closed by the time it tried to connect...
4. **Backend conn. recycles:** number of connections that needed to be re-opened by varnish to the backend server.

Hopefully this makes sense... other than the closed one, i am about 99% sure on the rest.

Comment: You know what? That might just be it :) Thanks for taking the time and I'll continue the search & report as I go